# How to set up static IP for DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp

I would like to set up a DHCP server on Ubuntu 10.10. How can I give it a static IP? I know this question is not very specific--I would like just you to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I've not yet flagged the question. But it can be rewritten as: "How do i set a static ip in Linux?" And would likely fit SU better than SF?

Answer (score 5):

edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and change the IP's below to suit your needs.

once complete, `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.1.14
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.1.0
    broadcast 10.0.1.255
    gateway 10.0.1.1
    subnet 10.0.1.0/24
```

Comment: I do this, but still when I type ifconfig, the inet adress is not the one I specified.